# Link back to site when user copy & paste text is not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, copy-paste

I want to add a link back to my site whenever a user copies text.

Whenever a user copies text from my site, I want to add a link back to my site. Like "Read more at My Site: URL". I am sure you have come across this before.

I found this code in the wild (for Wordpress) but it does not work at all. I'v tested it on Wordpress 3.8 using latest versions of Firefox and Safari. Is there any problems with the Javascript code? Or the Wordpress code itself?

```
function add_copyright_text() {
    if (is_single()) { ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function addLink() {
    if (
window.getSelection().containsNode(
document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0], true)) {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var oldselection = selection
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more: <?php the_title(); ?> <a href='<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>'><?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?></a>"; //Change this if you like
    var copy_text = selection + pagelink;
    var new_div = document.createElement('div');
    new_div.style.left='-99999px';
    new_div.style.position='absolute';

    body_element.appendChild(new_div );
    new_div.innerHTML = copy_text ;
    selection.selectAllChildren(new_div );
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(new_div );
    },0);
}
}


document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>

<?php
}
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_copyright_text');
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this can be done. We are not allowed to modify the OS in any way, this includes mucking with the clip board. This would be a security concern. With that being said, have you checked your JavaScript console while doing this to see any errors?

Comment: @JustinWood It can definitely be done. For example, copy some text here and check your clipboard: http://myanimelist.net/anime/10721/Mawaru_Penguindrum

Comment: @popnoodles This question is related to how to achieve this in the Wordpress platform, thus not a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Did you check your JavaScript console like I told you to?

Comment: i hate sites that do this and boycott them.

Comment: This kind of high level clipboard manipulation annoys more than it does good. The user can simply delete the forced message, so why even bother?

Comment: @user555 Because of this reason: https://www.google.com/#q="read+more+at+http:%2F%2Fmyanimelist.net*"

Comment: SEO spamming, lovely practice i wish you well in your business endeavours.

Comment: @Dagon Thank you, I am doing reasonable well actually. Respectfully, let me highlight that this is not a chat area. @ JustinWood Yes I did, no errors were displayed.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson No need to get snappy. We are just telling you that this kind of search engine manipulation might just get you blacklisted.

Comment: @user555 I completely understand, however note that this type of practice is not that uncommon. Most leading news sites (in top 1000 alexa rank) uses this. Which is why you have come across it often.

Comment: This appears to require you add the class entry-content, to a wraper for the content you want to inject your message into. I think this is junk though. This is not the kind of thing a high end site would do.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the same post and it didn't work for me either. What I did was change the code a bit to always allow this function.

```
<?php

/*******************************
*
*  Read more Copyright Text
*
*******************************/



function add_copyright_text() {
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var oldselection = selection
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> Read more at XXX: <?php the_title(); ?> <a href='<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>'><?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?></a>"; //Change this if you like
    var copy_text = selection + pagelink;
    var new_div = document.createElement('div');
    new_div.style.left='-99999px';
    new_div.style.position='absolute';

    body_element.appendChild(new_div );
    new_div.innerHTML = copy_text ;
    selection.selectAllChildren(new_div );
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(new_div );
    },0);
}


document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>

<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_copyright_text');
?>
```

It's not a big change. All I've done is remove the following conditionals:

1. `if (is_single()) { ?> .... <?php }`
2. `if (window.getSelection().containsNode(document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0], true)) { ...}`

Hope it helps you. Also, there is a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/append-link-on-copy/) that you might want to check out that is supposed to help you do this. (I haven't tried out it though).

Answer (score 1):

This is my better solution, it will link to the current URL opened :

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* give paste content link back
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function add_copyright_text() {
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function addLink() {
    var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var selection;
    selection = window.getSelection();
    var oldselection = selection
    var pagelink = "<br /><br /> link : <a href='http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>'>http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?></a>"; //Change this if you like
    var copy_text = selection + pagelink;
    var new_div = document.createElement('div');
    new_div.style.left='-99999px';
    new_div.style.position='absolute';

    body_element.appendChild(new_div );
    new_div.innerHTML = copy_text ;
    selection.selectAllChildren(new_div );
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        body_element.removeChild(new_div );
    },0);
}


document.oncopy = addLink;
</script>

<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_copyright_text');
?>
```